# Using jQuery to include an HTML element if the URL has a keyword and doesn't contain another keyword (at the same time)?

Tags: javascript

I want to add an image a page that has this at the end of the URL: `/esl-jobs-in-china/` but I don't want to include it in pages that have something like this at the end of the URL: `/esl-jobs-in-china/view/`.

So I wanted an if statement like this: Include the picture if the URL has `/esl-jobs-in-china/` and doesn't have `/view/`.

I tried this:

```
// Add image in Job Board
if(url.indexOf('/esl-jobs-in-china/') >= 0 && url.indexOf('/view/') >= -1) {
        $('.entry-content').prepend('<img width="425" height="282" src="http://goldstarteachers.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/3.jpg" class="attachment-full wp-post-image" alt="Shane English Schools China" title="Shane English Schools China">');
}
```

But I'm still getting the picture displayed in the pages containing `/esl-jobs-in-china/view/` in the URL

Any suggestions to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the second condition to ensure that there is no match on the string '/view/':

```
if(url.indexOf('/esl-jobs-in-china/') >= 0 && url.indexOf('/view/') == -1) {
        $('.entry-content').prepend('<img width="425" height="282" src="http://goldstarteachers.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/3.jpg" class="attachment-full wp-post-image" alt="Shane English Schools China" title="Shane English Schools China">');
}
```

since the expression `url.indexOf('/view/') >= -1` will always evaluate to true.

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf